# Retry whole test suite from the beginning in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a suite that has more than two test cases. Using Cypress, how can I retry all tests from the beginning of the test suite when one of the tests fails?

I have tried using the option `retries` from Cypress but it just retries the singular failed test, not all of the tests from the beginning of the suite. Anyone have any idea how to do this? Please help me.

```
describe('An user with an assigned report', {
  retries: {
    'runMode': 2,
    'openMode': 2
  }
}, () => {
  before(() => {
    const config = Cypress.env()
    cy.logout()
    cy.login(username, password)
  })

  after(() => {
    cy.logout()
  })

  it('should be able to add a comment', () => {
    cy.openReportWriterRightPanel()
  })

  it('should be able to add Incident Overview details', () => {
    // Click 'Incident Overview' and fill out form.
    cy.findByLabelText('currently active entity').click()
  })
}
```

Comment: I removed my answer suggesting `Cypress._.times` and edited your question to reflect the requirements you desire.

Comment: @OldSchooled did you found a solution? I need it to

Comment: Maybe a second, nested `describe` would work here? Retries only works on one test but if we wrapped all of the stuff we wanted to retry into another describe and nested that inside of the first describe that has the retries option, maybe cypress would treat the entire second describe block as one test and retry it all. Just guessing though, I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: I wanted to post same issue as you mentioned but after deep thinking, it make sense to see the problem differently. Indeed, in my case, I noticed that the test was always flaky inside the same `it('bla bla', {...})` function. So I succeed to fix that, just adding some code inside this `it` function to be able to get back the context needed (which was given by other previous `it`) but without affecting the test workflow. As a result, I don't need to re-start the test from beginning. Still not the best solution though, as you might have to this in multiple places, in case of multiple flaky `it`.